Proving that $(x^3 + 2x + 5, x^2 + 1) = (x^2 + 1, p)$ for some prime $p$.
I'm trying to show that the ideal $(x^3 + 2x + 5, x^2 + 1)$ is equal to the ideal $(x^2 + 1, p)$ for some prime $p$ (ideals in $\mathbb Z[x]$). My motivation is that I believe that $(x^3 + 2x + 5, x^2 + 1)$ is a maximal ideal and hence it must have the form that I am claiming it does. I just can't seem to find the prime that would do the trick.
Thanks.

You can try to prove that $(x^{3} + 2x + 5, x^{2} + 1) = (x + 5, x^{2} + 1) = (x + 5, 26)$, so $(x^{3} + 2x + 5, x^{2} + 1)$ is not a maximal ideal.

I believe your conjecture is false. By writing $I = (x^3 + 2x + 5, x^2 + 1) = (x^3 + 2x + 5 - x(x^2+1), x^2+1) = (x+5, x^2+1)$, we see that in the quotient $\mathbb{Z}[x]/I$, we have $[x] = [-5]$ and therefore $[x^2+1] = [26]$, so this quotient is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/26$, which is not even an integral domain, so your ideal is not even prime.

That's a typo. It should be $26$.

Thanks, @Justauser.  And in your (now deleted) answer, how did you know $I$ is not maximal?

Every maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ has the form $(f(x), p)$ where $p$ is prime integer and $f(x)$ is primitive integer polynomial that is irreducible modulo $p$. $(x^{3} + 2x + 5, x^{2} + 1) = (x + 5, 26)$ and $26$ is not a prime integer.

I see, @jhzg; thank you

@A. Thomas Yerger Yes it looks like I was wrong. But could you explain how one can show that the quotient is indeed isomorphic to $\mathbb Z / 26$ in a more rigorous way?

Calculations like these should be thought of as kind of like scratch work, they tell you how to define a map $\mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{Z}/26$. We send $x \mapsto -5$ and $1 \mapsto 1$. Now you prove that the kernel of this map is precisely your ideal, and conclude via the first isomorphism theorem. Alternatively, you can make a map $\mathbb{Z}[x]/I \to \mathbb{Z}/26$, and argue that it is a bijection. In my experience, both are fine, but the latter is more fiddly because of the equivalence classes.

$\, 3\:\!$ other ways to see the inequality $[\!$ vs. Euclidean reducing $(f,x^2\!+\!1)\,$ to $\,(\color{#c00}x\!+\!\color{#0a0}5,26)\,]$
$ \begin{align} &[\![1]\!]\ \ f=x^3\!+\!2x\!+\!5\:\!\in\:\! I=(x^2\!+\!1,p)\!\iff\! \overbrace{f\bmod x^2\!+\!1}^{\!\!\!\!\small\textstyle \color{#c00}1\:\!x+\color{#0a0}5}\:\!\in I\!\iff\,\!p\mid \color{#c00}1,\,\color{#0a0}5.\\[.6em]
&[\![2]\!]\ \ \text{${\bf Or}$ they are unequal in $\,\Bbb Z[x]/(x^2\!+\!1)\cong \Bbb Z[i]\!:\ (i\!+\!5)\neq (p)\,$ 
by $\,p\nmid\color{#c00}i\!+\!\color{#0a0}5;$}\\[.6em]
&[\![3]\!]\ \ \text{${\bf Or}$ they are unequal in $\,\Bbb Z[x]/p\!:\,\ (f,x^2\!+\!1)\,\neq\, (x^2\!+\!1)\ $ by $\!\underbrace{x^2\!+\!1\nmid f}_{\textstyle f(i)= \color{#c00}i\!+\!\color{#0a0}5\neq 0\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}\,$} \end{align}$
See quotient reciprocity for how the prior two methods are related.
